# CMS Joomla: How to clear joomla cache without using admin pages?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

How do I clear Joomla cache without using the admin pages?
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a cache cleaner plugin that would run with a CRON job.

[This one](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/cache-cleaner) might work.